# Xcode won't let me commit entire project (will only let me commit individual files)

Tags: xcode, github

I am attempting to commit and push an entire Xcode project to a github repo that contains other files and folders. I created this project (but not the repo), made the files and then connected it to the github repo (so my Xcode project does not contain everything in the repo). When I now try and commit and push, Xcode only gives me the option to do this for individual files, not the entire project. When my friend then tries to pull, he gets the files but not the .xcodeproj file, which I believe is necessary to run the simulator. We were thinking he could create a new Xcode project with the files on github in it and then work from that, but we are worried that could create different branches and merge conflicts. When he tries to commit and push projects on his computer, he can right-click the root folder in the file hierarchy and it gives him an option to commit and push the entire project. However, when I do this, it just lets me commit individual files. The same thing occurs if I try to commit and push via the source  control tab at the top of the screen. Why can I not commit and push the whole project?

Comment: try to commit and push using command line from your root project folder: git add ./ and git  commit -m "message"  and  git push -u origin --all